# Keep paragraphs/images on same page when gererating PDF

Tags: doxygen

I am heavily using PlantUML diagrams documenting my Project, since generated graphs
are sometimes real big it often happens I have a page break right before it,
thus separating paragraph describing image from the image itself.

How can I prevent this?

More generally: How can I force two or more paragraphs to be rendered on the same page
(possibly inserting a page break before the whole block)?

I *could* manually insert page breaks in strategic points (this is my current workaround),
but that means I need to modify whenever some piece of text is inserted/removed/modified.

Is there a better way?

Note: this is only relevant for latex/PDF output.

Comment: This is a very difficult problem and can, in my opinion, not directly be solved by doxygen, mainly due to the dynamic structure of the output. A solution might be that you add at designated placed something like `\latexonly \newline \endlatexonly`  or some similar code.

Comment: @albert: I assume you meant `\latexonly \pagebreak \endlatexonly`; many thanks for clarification why what I asked is not feasible..

Comment: Yes indeed you need a `pagebreak`